# How do you properly import the kikoso swipeable cards from github to Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, swipe-gesture

https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards

I haven't imported libraries before and I'm struggling to actually get it all working. Can somebody give me step by step instructions to properly import this library and get it working on Android studio, that would be great (starting from downloading the zip file).

Thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Comment: And I'm here wondering how TheQ didn't find that. After all, typing "import library in android studio" yields the same result... Just out of curiosity, **how did you miss that ???**

Comment: 2Dee I did the: dependencies 

{
   compile 'com.github.kikoso:SwipeableCards:1.1-RELEASE@aar'
}

and i clicked the "sync" button, but then I got an error in my Android manifest saying.

Error:(7, 9) Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:7:9

Comment: and 

Error:(7, 9) Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:7:9
 is also present at com.github.kikoso:SwipeableCards:1.1-RELEASE:12:9 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher)
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5 to override

Comment: And when I do it the other way, manually install the library, after I do:
compile project(":libs:Swipeable-Cards-master")

i get:

Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

And I did both his 5.1 and 6.1 ways...

Comment: there are a couple of build.gradle and settings.gradle. The ones I am using are for the app build.gradle and the very bottom of settings.gradle

Comment: so I added:

1)settings.gradle (for overall app)

include ':app', 'Swipeable-Cards-master'
project(':Swipeable-Cards-master').projectDir = new File('libs/Swipeable-Cards-master')

Comment: 2)build.gradle (for app)

 compile project(":Swipeable-Cards-master")

and i get:

Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by adding
`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` 
to manifest tag and adding this 
`tools:replace="android:icon"`to your application tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need the "how-to" guide but here it is:

**Import using gradle**

Go to your `build.gradle` (module app) file, there you will find the dependencies section.
There you will paste the compile command.

```
compile 'com.github.kikoso:SwipeableCards:1.1-RELEASE@aar'
```

Android Studio then will tell you that the gradle files have changed since last sync and will give you in the upper corner a `Sync now` text. You just click it and everything will synchronize.